# which is the best way to associate many values to a single value of another table?

Tags: sql

I want know which is the best way to associate a few values to only one value. I have:

```
TABLE keyword
id |keyword
1  | agence web
2  | mobile
3  | print

TABLE services
id | serivice | id_keyword
1    web          1
2    web          2
3    web          3
```

Of course, the table keyword and services are join with id of keyword and id_keyword of services. What s the best way to associate these values?

Comment: What do you mean by "associate"? How familiar are you with database-theory in general?

Comment: I'm learning. For example, in the table services the word "web" it s associate at agence web, mobile and print. What s the best way to structure the table and make this combination?

Comment: You need an *associative table*, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should normalize your database [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization),
remove `id_keyword` from `service` table and 
create a new table 
eg: `services_rel_keyword` with columns `service_id` and `keyword_id`

fetch them using `join`

Or you can use JSON or Array datatype if you are using PostgreSQL or MySQL

[PostgreSQL JSON link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/) and [MySQL JSON link](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/)

and if you are using MSSQL server [JSON link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-in-sql-server-2016/)

Comment: Thank you ! I need this.

Comment: @Zed93 No Problem, Happy Coding <3